# ASP.NET MVC How to Pass radiobutton selected value from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a dynamically generated set of radio buttons. I just want to get the selected value across to my controller. I tried few things but it does not work. I can only get hidden field values set by the form for a different purpose. 
These do not work – they return nothing:

```
var YourRadioButton2 = Request.Form["wc"];
string selectedTechnology = form["wc"];
```

Is there a way I can get the selected radio buttons across to the controller. These radiobutton values are dynamically generated.

the View

```
<%--wired choices--%>
         <tr > Wired Choices </tr>
        <% for (var i = 0; i < subform.wiredchoices.Count; i++) %>
        <%{ %> 
            <tr>  

                <td> <input type="radio" name="wc" value="<%:    subform.wiredchoices.ElementAt(i).WiredChoiceItem %>" > </td>
                <td><%:    subform.wiredchoices.ElementAt(i).WiredChoiceItem %> </td>
```

The controller

```
if (rcpt.Form.Is("VoIP"))
            {
                 Response.Write("<br />" + "wc " + wc);

                 List<String> listValues = new List<String>();
                 foreach (string key in Request.Form.AllKeys)
                 {                    
                         listValues.Add(Request.Form[key]);
                         Response.Write("<br />" + "first values  " + Request.Form[key]);
                 }

                 // Loop through every checkbox
                 foreach (var key2 in form.AllKeys)
                 {
                             Response.Write("<br />" + "second values  " + key2);
                 }


                //See Radiobutton selections
                var YourRadioButton = Request.Form["wc"];
                Response.Write("<br />" + "YourRadioButton " + YourRadioButton);
                string selectedTechnology = form["wc"];
                Response.Write("<br />" + "YourRadioButton " + selectedTechnology);

                var YourRadioButton2 = Request.Form["wlc"];
                Response.Write("<br />" + "YourRadioButton " + YourRadioButton2);
                string selectedTechnology2 = form["wlc"];
                Response.Write("<br />" + "YourRadioButton " + selectedTechnology2);

                Response.Write("<br />" + "VoIP Hire ");
                String wiredChoice = "test"; //assign value from radio button here
                String wiredLessChoice = "test"; //assign value from radio button here

                // Stor e submitting page to return to
                ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = fields.formType;



                </tr>
            <%} %>
```

Comment: U Need to have the radio Button inside a form with a Button, when Button is triggered the radio button values should be sent to the controller, otherwise I think Ajax could be also a good practice to use. But then u post value to Ajax and from Ajax to controller.

Answer (score 12):

Your code reminds me of those old days of using web forms. Ah ! Thank God!. We have ASP.NET MVC now and we can do this in a clean way in MVC.

Let's start creating a view model for our view.

```
public class Technology
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
}

public class CreateUserViewModel
{   
    [Required]
    public int? SelectedTechnology { set; get; }   

    public List<Technology> Technologies { set; get; }

    // Add other properties as needed by your view
    public string UserName { set; get; }
}
```

Now in your GET action method, create an object of this view model, Load the `Technologies` collection property and send that to the view.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var vm = new CreateUserViewModel();
  vm.Technologies = GetTechnologyList();
  return View(vm);
}
private List<Technology> GetTechnologyList()
{
    //Hard coded a list of items here, You may replace it with 
    // Items from your db table
    return new List<Technology>
    {
        new Technology {Id = 1, Name = "DSL"},
        new Technology {Id = 2, Name = "VOIP"},
        new Technology {Id = 3, Name = "Dialup"},
        new Technology {Id = 4, Name = "Magic"}
    };
}
```

Now in your razor view, which is strongly typed to our CreateUserViewModel class

```
@model ReplaceYourNamespaceHere.CreateUserViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

   <h4>Select a technology</h4>
    foreach (var item in Model.Technologies)
    {
       <div> @Html.RadioButtonFor(s => s.SelectedTechnology, item.Id) @item.Name</div>
    }
    <input type="submit"/>
}
```

This will render the form with radio buttons for the items in the `Technologies` collection. When you submit the form, the selected technology's id will be set to the `SelectedTechnology` property of the posted form/model.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateUserViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Selected Technology Id is in model.SelectedTechnology
        // to do :Save and Redirect
    }
    //Reload the radio button list data
    model.Technologies = GetTechnologyList();
    return View(model);
}
```

Trust me, Here it is :)

[image]

If you want to preselect one radion button on your create( or edit ) view, you can set the `SelectedTechnology` property value the Id of the technology you want to selected.

```
 var vm = new CreateUserViewModel();
 vm.Technologies = GetTechnologyList();

 vm.SelectedTechnology = 3 ; //replace with a non-hard coded value 

 return View(vm);
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the guidance. This looks promising. Before I start implementing, I have to ask if the view you have coded in razor - would in still work in aspx? Because My project is big and is done in aspx instead of razor. Can you provide the same in aspx syntax please?

Comment: Awesome solution, fixed it perfectly for me! I always tell myself, if I have the model setup correctly, everything flows like a melted chocolate river! THANK YOU Shyju!