# How to display only certain items for Radiobuttonlistfor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

In my MVC application, I am generating a Radiobuttonlist dynamically from the database. There are 15 records but I want to display just first 5 of them. Is it possible to do this using RadiobuttonlistFor or any other way?

Thanks.

Comment: can you show your code?why can you just filter first 5 fro db itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wherever you are generating or using the collection which holds the list of radio button list items, you may use LINQ `Take` method to get only 5.

```
yourRadioButtonList = yourRadioButtonList.Take(5);
```

Assuming yourRadioButtonList  is of type `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: By the way, how do I get the selected item in the controller? I want to pass it as a parameter to a stored procedure.

Comment: Depends on how you render the radio buttons. Take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33989863/asp-net-mvc-how-to-pass-radiobutton-selected-value-from-view-to-controller/33990249#33990249